# Trigger - Write SELECT Result directly into :new.field

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, subquery

I am actually training in oracle SQL basics and I have created a trigger that looks like this one (it works!):

```
create or replace TRIGGER insert_refereenation
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Game
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
v_nation_id NUMBER(4) := '';
v_nationname VARCHAR2(100) := '';

BEGIN

SELECT Nation_id
INTO v_nation_id
FROM referre
WHERE referee_id= :new.referee_id;

SELECT Name
INTO v_nationname
FROM Nation
WHERE Nation_id = v_nation_id;

:NEW.referee_nation_name:= v_nationname;

END;
```

This trigger works fine but I have two simple questions:

1. Is it possible to write the result from the second SELECT right into the: NEW.referee_nation_name field? So I wouldn´t need the second variable.
2. Do you see other things which can get optimized?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join so that you have only one query instead of two, and use the `:new.column_name` directly in the `into` clause:

```
SELECT n.name
INTO   :new.referee_nation_name
FROM   referee r
JOIN   nation n ON r.nation_id = n.nation_id
WHERE  r.referee_id = :new.referee_id;
```